# symfony admin generator form object

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, admin-generator

Hey guys, I've used the `Symfony admin generator` for a module.

Everything is working, but when the form for my model is instantiated, I need to pass in my own option.

I could do this myself by overriding the executeNew, executeCreate functions in `myModuleActions.class.php` (which extends myModuleAutoActions).

But I was hoping for a neater solution?

Perhaps overriding one of the configuration classes is the way to go. I basically need to add the current `sf_user` object (`$this->getUser`) as an "`sf_user`" option for the form, to avoid using `sfContext` in the `myModuleForm`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Overriding the "sfModelGeneratorConfiguration::getForm" method in myModuleGeneratorConfiguration could work, but would still involve me using sfContext to get the current sf_user object

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, jolly18.

I would just use sfContext.  For example, in my app, I have a subform that creates a new Note object and assigns the user to it.  In my form's `configure()` I have:

```
$new_note->setAuthor(sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getUsername());
```

I see [the book calls this "The fastest but ugly way"](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_custom_widget_and_validator_classes) because it makes "a big coupling between the form and the context, making the testing and reusability more difficult."  But in practice... this works well and I can move on.

Answer (score 1):

i've been facing this problem for a while but symfony always surprises me with some neat code that i was not aware of.

I assume you'r using sfPropelPlugin, quite standar, if you checkout the code generated in cache (note: this code will be available once you tried to open the module from the browser, so firts try to look at it so we dont get in trouble :P) you may see something like:

`cache/{application_name}(generally frontend or backend)/dev(enviromnemt)/autoModule_name( look here for the module)/`:

- lib
- action

The action folder contains an action.class.php file that defines all actions generated by the generator (executeNew, Edit, Create, Update, etc). If you look a the implementation of executeNew and executeEdit, you can see that they ask a configuration instace the actual form to display, here is an example:

```
  public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
    $this->PaymentOrder = $this->form->getObject();
  }
```

The configuration var containt an instance of a configuration class defined in the lib folder i mentioned earlier. That class tweaks the form to fit the object needs (generally by setting a fresh object instance).

So here comes the magic, the classes you see in your module extend from those in cache, so by pure logic, if you modifi the `getForm()` method in the main module/lib folder to fit your needs, you wont have to hack forms by getting user valuer where you shouldn't.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

if module was generated using admin-generator :

in `apps/backend/modules/books/actions/actions.class.php`

modify: in

```
executeEdit(){

//leave rest unchanged

$values=array('activity_id'=>$activity_id, 'book_id'=>$book_id, 'todo_id'=>$todo_id, 'user_id'=>$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId());


    $this->form = new TabelBooksForm($TabelBooks, $values);
}
```

modify: in

```
executeNew(){

//leave rest unchanged

$values=array('activity_id'=>$activity_id, 'book_id'=>$book_id, 'todo_id'=>$todo_id, 'user_id'=>$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId());

    $this->form = new TabelBooksForm(array(), $values);
}
```

in TabelBooksForm.class.php

```
public function configure()
  {

   if ($this->isNew()) {
    $this->setWidget('book_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
    $this->setDefault('book_id', $this->getOption('book_id'));    

    $this->setWidget('activity_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
    $this->setDefault('activity_id', $this->getOption('activity_id'));    

    $this->setWidget('todo_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
    $this->setDefault('todo_id', $this->getOption('todo_id'));  
  }
}
```